# Vuejs: CSS is loaded in the head instead of the shadow-root

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm trying to use a [vue-tel-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tel-input) within a Vue Web Component. However, the vue-tel-input CSS is not loaded by the the web component as expected.

The CSS that is loaded in the head instead of the shadow-root.** I'm not sure how to load the css in the shadow-root.

**Steps to reproduce:**
[Here](https://github.com/benjaminroy/vue-web-component) you can see a simple Vue.js App using a vue-tel-input field. By building the web component (`npm run build-wc`) and by opening the demo.html in the dist folder, you can see the vue-tel-input field not rendering correctly.

See picture [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KNU0K8B0gy1dK6JjGa_I0336zXDojmdH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `Vue.use(VueTelInput)` should be declared on your main.js as his [documentation](https://github.com/EducationLink/vue-tel-input) says.

Comment: The problem seems to be the css that is loaded in the head instead of the shadow-root.

Comment: Did you try this? `import 'vue-tel-input/dist/vue-tel-input.css';`

Comment: This file does not exist in the last version of vue-tel-input.

Comment: Having the same problem, scoped SCSS / CSS in components does work but when I add a component from a package the CSS gets added in the head outside of the Shadow root of the web component.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `npm run build-wc` command to compile your Vue component into a web component then you would also need to keep the CSS also part of the same file.

So in your [code](https://github.com/benjaminroy/vue-web-component/blob/master/src/App.vue) add `import 'vue-tel-input/dist/vue-tel-input.css';` as well or keep in as part of  tag in your single file component. in that way the chunked CSS will be part of shadow root.